# Fastapi asynchronous response (bg tasks)

Tags: asynchronous, background

I am using fastapi for the first time in a project.
I receive information from an html form and return a `HTMLResponse` object to indicate that the program is running in the background (thanks to the `BackgroundTask` object). Is there a way to return another HTML file and to make my browser switch to that once the background task is over?

Sorry if I use the wrong terminology, but I am no expert.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

So what you need to do here is implement websockets. After your task is finished you can have to send a message on the websockets intimidating that the task has finished. 
Think of it like a notification service.
You can find some documentation [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/websockets/)
You will have to connect to the websocket from your frontend as well.
Do you research on this, I'm sure you will find a lot of documentation and articles on this idea.